# MySQL Triggerupdate

Tags: mysql

i have a question about mySQL and triggers. Ive read so much about it, but i dont check it. Now i think i have to explain my problem specific.

I have a database with Games you can rent. i have the tables invoice, games, customers and management.

If somebody is renting a game, i want to update my rented games and stored games.

So if i write in a DATE when the game was rent, i want that the rented games is growing by 1 and the stored games are going down by.

example:

invoice(customer,...,...,...,.., rent date: 2015-11-27, bring back date: .....)

management(....., total games, rented games +1, stored games -1)

I hope its clear what i mean. I know my databasestructure sucks, but i really dont like it and im just doing it for university... :(

Thx in advance to all your databaselovingpeople who can help me :D

best regards

Comment: You have to use an AFTER INSERT trigger. What have you tried so far?

Comment: CREATE TRIGGER `Lagerbestand_Trigger` AFTER INSERT ON `invoice` FOR EACH ROW INSERT INTO invoice(day of rent) VALUES ('Lagerbestand_Trigger AFTER INSERT')   thats how it looks like now.   But i dont check, how do my database know , that the rented games have to change now if i fill in a date in my invoice table.